# Expo Start web stuck on loading

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

[image]Please help My expo react native app working fine on android. but its stuck on loading on web version when I run it for web. please help thanks.

Comment: any screenshot?

Comment: hey see there is welcome page its keep loading

Comment: Ok I got the solution Thanks. There is await thats why its keep loading

Comment: hmm. no problem

Comment: But tell me one think why there is problem with touch on expo web sometimes it works. sometimes it not works

Comment: expo sometimes shows this behavior, solution is to stop and reload your project